# Calling overloaded functions from child class

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

I have 2 classes that are very similar. Let's say `bird` and `hawk`

```
class Bird
{
  ...
  public void fly()
  {
    //do a lot of stuff here
  }
}

class Hawk extends Bird
{
  public void fly()
  {
    parent.fly() // how can I call the overloaded parent method?
    //a couple changes specific to hawk here
  }
}
```

I want to be able to have both Birds and Hawks. When calling fly() on a Hawk, I still want to run the Bird's fly method, only with a couple of changes at the end. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing so? Its overriden method rather than overloaded method.

Comment: parent.fly() isn't the right syntax. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: use `super.fly();` instead of accessing it like `parent.fly();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `super` keyword like:

```
class Hawk extends Bird {
    public void fly() {
        super.fly() // use keyword super instead of parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I get this error: `Implicit super constructor Bird() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`

Comment: are you sure you are not using super() @penu. The above code should work fine

Comment: I'm using it just like that. I'm not sure why it's doing that. My Hawk is in a new file called Hawk.java. Do I need to have a `using Bird.java` or something at the top?

Comment: Because you have no args constructor in Bird @penu and you havent defined that in Hawk? So if you like define default constructor like `public Bird(){}` in Bird class.

Comment: So apparently I can't just use all the parent constructors. I have to copy them in the child classes. I added constructor `Hawk(int x, int y, World w){super(x,y,w)}` and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Use Super keyword . We simply use Super keyword when we want to call super class method/constructor

```
public void fly()
  {
    Super.fly() 
  }
```

Comment: Two things:  `super` is in lower-case, and this answer adds nothing new to what was previously answered above.